# Онклик после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите почему не работает онклики после загрузки страницы:

```
<ul class="filter-m">
    <li id="cl" data-filter=".sandwiches" ><span>Любимым людям</span></li>
    <li data-filter=".il"><span>Я тебя люблю</span></li>
</ul>
```

Вот блок:

```
<div class="portfolio full">
    <div class="sandwiches-block">
        <div class="item sandwiches col-1-3 h-300" style="background-image: url('assets/img/l/1.jpg');background-repeat: round;">
        </div>
        <div class="item sandwiches col-1-3 h-300" style="background-image: url('assets/img/l/2.jpg');background-repeat: round;">
        </div>
        <div class="item sandwiches col-1-3 h-300" style="background-image: url('assets/img/l/3.jpg');background-repeat: round;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

но он не отрабатывает:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#cl').click()
    });            
</script>
```

Comment: а что вы ожидаете от этого кода?

Answer (score 3):

Всё работает. Главное указать клик после самой функции, которая должна выполняться при клике

```js
$(function() { 
   $('#cl').click(function() {
     alert('Кликнулось :)')
   });
   $('#cl').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul><li id="cl">Элемент</li></ul>
```